# How do I determine the camera rotation in world space (not orientation of a Charuco board) in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, aruco

In OpenCV, I am using a Charuco board, have calibrated the camera, and use SolvePnP to get rvec and tvec. (similar to the sample code). I am using a stationary board, with a camera on a  circular rig which orbits the board.  I'm a noob with this, so please bear with me if this is something simple I am missing.

I understand that I can use Rodrigues() to get the 3x3 rotation matrix for the board orientation from rvec, and that I can transform the tvec value into world coordinates using -R.t() * tvec (in c++).

However, as I understand it, this 3x3 rotation R gives the orientation of the board with respect to the camera, so it's not quite what need.  I want the rotation of the camera itself, which is offset from R by (I think) the angle between tvec and the z axis in camera space. (because the camera is not always pointing at the board origin, but it is always pointing down the z axis in camera space).  Is this correct?

How do I find the additional rotation offset and convert it to a 3x3 rotation matrix which I can combine with R to get the actual camera orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you capture N frames of the Charuco board from the camera. Then, you have N transformations taking a point in the camera frame to the same point in the Charuco board frame. This is obtained from the Charuco board poses for every frame.

Say we denote a linear transformation from one coordinate frame to another  as

T<sub>4x4</sub> = [R<sub>3x3</sub>, t<sub>3x1</sub>; 0<sub>1x3</sub>, 1]

If we look at a point P from the board coordinate frame and refer to it as P<sub>board</sub>. Similarly, we look at that point from camera 1 referred to as c<sub>1</sub>, camera 2 as c<sub>2</sub> and so on.

So, we could write:

P<sub>board</sub> = T<sub>1</sub>P<sub>c<sub>1</sub></sub>
P<sub>board</sub> = T<sub>2</sub>P<sub>c<sub>2</sub></sub>
.
.
.
P<sub>board</sub> = T<sub>N</sub>P<sub>c<sub>N</sub></sub>

From what I understand, you need camera's rotation say from the starting point (assume that camera is at zero rotation in the frame 1). So, you could express every subsequent frame in terms of P<sub>c<sub>1</sub></sub> instead of P<sub>board</sub>.

So, we could say 
T<sub>2</sub>P<sub>c<sub>2</sub></sub> = T<sub>1</sub>P<sub>c<sub>1</sub></sub>
or, P<sub>c<sub>2</sub></sub> = T<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup>T<sub>1</sub>P<sub>c<sub>1</sub></sub>
Similarly, P<sub>c<sub>N</sub></sub> = T<sub>N</sub><sup>-1</sup>T<sub>1</sub>P<sub>c<sub>1</sub></sub>

You could recover R<sub>N</sub> for taking point from camera position N to camera position 1 by looking at the rotation part of T<sub>N</sub><sup>-1</sup>T<sub>1</sub>.